# Pasting into flag comment other box leaves flag comment box disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags

I was trying to flag multiple comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263731/fconnect-login-fails-for-newly-created-fb-user-in-iphone/6264079#6264079) as other because, well, I wanted to. I was going to paste the same explanation into the "other" reason box.  But if you paste into the flag comment text box, the flag comment box is still disabled.

[image: Flag comment disabled.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting that you have "i can't click flag comment!!" conveniently in the clipboard... psychic!

Anyways, fixed next deploy.